# Create ggplot with color labels in one column and values in another column with legend combine both

Tags: r, ggplot2

As in this reproducible example, I'm trying to make a `ggplot` by assigning predefined colors in the `df` column `colors` according to the values in another column, `value`. I succeed with this code, but unfortunately the color is not displayed in the legend.

```
# create reproducible dataframe
df <- data.frame(runif(500, min=-6, max=3))
names(df)[1] <- "value"
lat <- data.frame(runif(500, min=-5, max=30))  
names(lat)[1] <- "lat"
df <- cbind(df, lat)
lon <- data.frame(runif(500, min=40, max=50))    
names(lon)[1] <- "lon"
df <- cbind(df, lon)
rm(lat, lon)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(colors = 
           ifelse(value > 2  , "#78d058", 
                  ifelse(value >= 1 & value <= 2  , "#a8dc94", 
                         ifelse(value >= 0 & value <= 1  , "#efefef", 
                                ifelse(value < 0 & value >= -1, "#f5a2a2",
                                       ifelse(value < -2 & value >= -3, "#f97c7c",
                                              ifelse(value < -3 & value >= -4, "#fc5555",
                                                     ifelse(value < -4 & value >= -5, "#ff2f2f",
                                                            "#af2020"))))))))

# ggplot
ggplot(data = df) +
  aes(x = lat, y = lon, fill = value) +
  geom_point(colour = df$colors)
```

[image]

Are there any suggestions on how I could create a legend with both values and colors, in a continuous way?

Thanks for help or suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an other approach using `breaks` and `scale_fill_gradientn()`:

```
library(ggplot2)

breaks <- c(-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3)
colors <- c("#af2020", "#ff2f2f", "#fc5555", "#f97c7c", "#f5a2a2",
            "#efefef", "#a8dc94", "#78d058", "#78d058")


ggplot(data = df, aes(x = lat, y = lon, fill = value)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 3, color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = colors, values = scales::rescale(breaks),
                       breaks = breaks, guide = "colourbar") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: I wondered about adding this to my answer @TarJae, but good to see it as a separate answer. I think if a discrete colour scale uses a gradation of 8 colours, you might as well go the whole hog and have a gradient. This may even have been what the OP was hoping to achieve in a very indirect way.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manually creating color bins in your data with a deeply nested `ifelse`, you can just use `scale_color_stepsn`, which is designed for exactly this use-case.

Note that your method of creating data frames is very long-winded and inefficient. The following code does the same as your own, except it includes a nice legend.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(value = runif(500, min = -6, max = 3),
                 lat = runif(500, min = -5, max = 30),
                 lon = runif(500, min = 40, max = 50))

ggplot(data = df) +
  aes(x = lat, y = lon, color = value) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_stepsn(colors = c("#af2020", "#ff2f2f", "#fc5555", "#f97c7c",
                                "#f5a2a2", "#efefef", "#a8dc94", "#78d058"),
                     breaks = seq(-5, 2))
```

[image]